# How Can I Get Data From more then 1 page from JSON API and put them into 1 json file with PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, fetch-api, array-merge

This Is My API URL :

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=250&page=1
```

We Can Have page=2 AND page=3 AND etc ...
I Want To Fetch Data From page 1 Until page 6 And Then Put All Of Them Into 1 json File file.json .
I'm Using this code below :

```
    for ($j=1;$j<=6;$j++){
    $coin_market_cap_url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=250&page='.$j;
    $coin_market_cap_result = json_decode(getCurlAgent($coin_market_cap_url, true), true);
    for ($i=0;$i<250;$i++){
        $coins[$i]['name']=$coin_market_cap_result[$i]['name'];
        $coins[$i]['symbol']=$coin_market_cap_result[$i]['symbol'];
    }
}
$coins = json_encode($coins);
if ($coins){
    file_put_contents("file.json", $coins);
}
```

How Can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Erik I've done that please remove -1 score, thanks

Comment: you're already using a for loop, use another for loop from 1 to 6 and change the url every iteration.

Comment: @Erik I've added another loop for pages but that only put the last page into my file , i want to add all of 6 pages into file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are replacing the first  250 entries in the for loop

**Working Code**

```
<?php

$coins = [];
for ($j = 1; $j <= 6; $j++) {
    $coin_market_cap_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=250&page={$j}";
    $coin_market_cap_result = json_decode(file_get_contents($coin_market_cap_url), true);
    foreach ($coin_market_cap_result as $coin) {
        $coins[] = [
            'name' => $coin['name'],
            'symbol' => $coin['symbol'],
        ];
    }
}

$coins = json_encode($coins);
if ($coins) {
    file_put_contents("file.json", $coins);
}
```